# Windows 2008 cscript.exe Application error 0xc0000142

Tags: heap-memory, wsh

After cscript.exe crashed, which ran fine for a few days then crashed at every and all instances, after that, Tidal agent (a batch jobs management s/w) started to crash.  Need reboot to recover from the errors.  Does anyone have any experience about this rarely used cscript.exe, and its behaviors, and what applications may have spawned this process, or how to trace the sources?

errors:

> Faulting application cscript.exe, version 5.7.6002.18960, 
>   time stamp 0x5257601e, faulting module kernel32.dll, version 6.0.6002.19623,

Answer (score 0):

Most likely source is Win 2008 Health Service Modules, which launches cscript.exe at every 2 to 15 minutes interval. The script may be blocked by AV.  After a few days, it may have caused heap to overflow, and crashed the system. The root cause may be that someone is configuring SCOM or AV incorrectly.

ETW: Operations manager event ID 21406:

Command executed:   "C:\Windows\system32\cscript.exe" /nologo "MpDiscovery.vbs" {47E94BF5-C34B-7BDD-F6DA-DD648464CCB3} {02CB7C34-1EEB-821E-2E9C-488387B6266F} HOUCO2IMAGE1..com
Working Directory:  C:\Program Files\System Center Operations Manager\Agent\Health Service State\Monitoring Host Temporary Files 1662\3047\

and event 21405:
The process started at 6:21:25 AM failed to create System.PropertyBagData, no errors detected in the output.  The process exited with 1

Command executed:   "C:\Windows\system32\cscript.exe" /nologo "Microsoft.Windows.Server.Legacy.FreeSpace.vbs" HOUCO2IMAGE1..com false
Working Directory:  C:\Program Files\System Center Operations Manager\Agent\Health Service State\Monitoring Host Temporary Files 1184\1409\

One or more workflows were affected by this.

Workflow name: Microsoft.Windows.Server.2008.Legacy.LogicalDisk.FreeSpace.Monitor